# Using semicolon to separate a background job from the following one?

Tags: background-process

Can we use semicolon to separate a background job from the following one?

```
$ nohup evince tmp1.pdf &; nohup evince tmp.pdf &
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Answer (score 18):

No.

First of all, that's a semicolon, not a comma. A comma can't ever be used to separate jobs. For background jobs, nothing else is needed. The `&` already serves to separate jobs:

```
$ nohup evince tmp1.pdf & nohup evince tmp.pdf &
```

Of course, in this case, it would be simpler to run

```
$ nohup evince tmp1.pdf tmp.pdf &
```